# Stripe and NextJS 13 Create Checkout Session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, next.js13

I am getting a 500 error and I have narrowed down the bug to my priceId being undefined. I feel like I have defined the priceId but whatever I do it still isn't working. I have successfully used a GET request to list all the prices I have made in my Stripe dashboard. So, since I did create all the prices I know I just have to retrieve the price.id and use that.

I will post screenshots of my code below. Any help would be appreciated. Been stuck on this for hours. Even tried Stripe support but I know it's a coding error somewhere.

api/payment  - route.jsx

```
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

export async function POST(request) {
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  const { data } = request.body;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
  });

  return NextResponse.json(session.url);
}
```

Pricing Card.jsx - component client side - I did console.log(price.id) inside of the the handleSubscription function and I do get the price.ids.

```
function PricingCard({price}) {

const handleSubscription = async (e, price) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(price.id)
      const {data} = await axios.post('/api/payment', {
       priceId: price.id,
      });
      window.open(data)
      console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <div className="border-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-4 text-center mt-10 max-w-[1040px]">
      <div>
        <div className="bg-gray-100 h-28 items-center font-bold">
          <h4 className="text-3xl">{price.nickname}</h4>
          <p>{dynamicSubTitle(price)}</p>
          <h3 className='text-xl mt-2'>First 2,000lbs Included</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-4">
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">
              {(price.unit_amount / 100).toLocaleString("en-US", {
                style: "currency",
                currency: "USD",
              })}{" "}
            </h1>
            <h3 className="pl-1 mt-2">Additional weight just $.05 /lb</h3>
          </div>
          <ul className='flex justify-center'>
            <li className="text-xl font-bold">{dynamicDescription(price)}</li>
          </ul>
          {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(price, null, 4)}</pre> */}
          <button
            onClick={(e) => handleSubscription(e, price)}
            className="mt-8 flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-[#f1592a] py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
          > Rent This Dumpster
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default PricingCard;
```

When I console.log(price.id) above the axios.post in PricingCard, I do end up getting the correct id back. However, when I try to console.log(price.id) below the priceId: price.id I get nothing, even console.log(priceId) gets me nothing

Parent component where I fetch the prices from Stripe as well.

```
'use client'

import Image from "next/image";
import dumpster3 from "../../public/dumpster3.jpg";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PricingCard from "../components/PricingCard";

export default function Pricing() {
  const [prices, setPrices] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
       fetchPrices()
   }, [])

   const fetchPrices = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get('/api/getproducts')
    console.log(data)
    setPrices(data)
   }



  return (
    <section className="w-full">
      <div className="w-screen h-[60vh] relative">
        <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-[60vh] bg-gradient-to-t from-black to-transparent z-10" />
        <Image
          className="absolute inset-0 z-1"
          src={dumpster3}
          alt="/"
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          priority
        />
        <div className="pt-36 sm:pt-0 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <h1 className="text-5xl md:text-5xl lg:text-7xl font-bold text-white mb-8 z-[100]">
            PRICING
          </h1>
          <p className="text-center text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-4xl text-white font-medium z-[100]">
            ORDER ONLINE BELOW 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-auto max-w-4xl text-center mt-10 items-center">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold leading-7 text-[#f1592a]">
            Pricing
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-2 text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl">
            Choose the right dumpster for&nbsp;you
          </p> 
          <p className="mx-auto mt-6 max-w-2xl text-lg leading-8 text-gray-600 sm:text-center">
          Check out all the information to make the correct decision or give us a call!
        </p>
        </div>
       
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-8 max-w-[1040px] items-center mx-auto">
        {prices && 
        prices.map((price) => (
          <PricingCard
           price={price}
           key={price.id}
           />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add `console.log(priceId)` before creating a checkout session and check if the `priceId` is indeed something like `price_xxx` instead of undefined value? If it's undefined value, it's likely that you retrieve the incorrect parameter from the request body (which is likely to be `data.priceId` instead).

Comment: Yea I am getting undefined priceId on the frontend client code. but I am getting price.id like I should. There is obviously something wrong in my PricingCard.jsx file but can't seem to figure it out

Comment: in your payment api, what is the value of `priceId` ? It isn't defined anywhere in your codes. In your PricingCard, check the parent component to see if price is defined, if your child component is not getting the price variable right, then problem lies in your parent component (which is not shown in ur codes)

Comment: I will add the parent component now to the question. Just added it. If you can help me out; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs 13 doesn't accept req.body anymore to get a request for the body content.

//try using the code below

const {data} = await res.json();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).